# Play website videos on mobile native video player

Tags: android, video, mobile

I am stuck with a problem to play videos on mobile phone's native player. I had searched the web a lot. And got many answers , but they are still not working for me.

My code is here

```
<embed src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/VID-20141027-WA0003.mp4"></embed>
```

it's playing  on the same page , but what i need is to choose which player among my native player should play the video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<video id="video" autobuffer height="240" width="360">
<source src="/img/VID-20141027-WA0003.mp4">
</video>
```

and add click in JS (optional)

```
var video = document.getElementById('video');
video.addEventListener('click',function(){
  video.play();
},false);
```